# How to connect 2 running containers to each other in docker-compose?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose

So I’ve got this simple Python Flask application where I have 2 services: Application and Database. I want the Application (Flask app) to connect to the Database service (PostgreSQL).

Now when I comment out the Application service and run a `docker-compose up`, it fires up the Database service which is exposed on port 5432. Then when I run the Flask app locally and try to connect, it works.

Now I uncomment the Application service and run a `docker-compose up --build`. It builds and starts both services. But then when I visit http://localhost:5000 the app **crashes due to a connection error (refused)**.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  application:
    depends_on:
      - database
    build: ./core
    restart: always
    networks:
      - cbr-open-data
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./core:/app

  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    networks:
      - cbr-open-data
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER:      ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB:        ${DATABASE_NAME}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  cbr-open-data:
    driver: bridge
```

### config/connection.py

```
import psycopg2
import pandas

connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    database = '...',
    user = '...',
    password = '...',
    port='5432'
)

users = pandas.read_sql('SELECT * FROM users', connection)
```

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from config.connection import users

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(users)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### Error

```
➜  cbr-open-data git:(master) ✗ docker-compose up
Creating network "cbr-open-data_cbr-open-data" with driver "bridge"
Creating cbr-open-data_database_1 ... done
Creating cbr-open-data_application_1 ... done
Attaching to cbr-open-data_database_1, cbr-open-data_application_1
application_1  |  * Environment: development
application_1  |  * Debug mode: on
application_1  |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
application_1  |  * Restarting with stat
application_1  |  * Debugger is active!
application_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 159-218-115
database_1     | 
database_1     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
database_1     | 
database_1     | 2020-02-09 18:10:37.188 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
database_1     | 2020-02-09 18:10:37.189 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
database_1     | 2020-02-09 18:10:37.189 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
database_1     | 2020-02-09 18:10:37.192 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
database_1     | 2020-02-09 18:10:37.303 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-09 13:21:34 UTC
database_1     | 2020-02-09 18:10:37.330 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

THIS IS WHEN I VISIT THE FLASK APP ON 5000.

application_1  | 172.28.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2020 18:10:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
application_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
application_1  |     raise value
application_1  |   File "/app/app.py", line 2, in <module>
application_1  |     from config.connection import users
application_1  |   File "/app/config/connection.py", line 9, in <module>
application_1  |     port='5432'
application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
application_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
application_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
application_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
application_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
application_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
application_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
application_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
application_1  | 172.28.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2020 18:10:41] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
application_1  | 172.28.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2020 18:10:41] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
application_1  | 172.28.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2020 18:10:41] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
application_1  | 172.28.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2020 18:10:42] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
application_1  | 172.28.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2020 18:10:42] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Can someone explain why the Database service is refusing connection from the Application service but accepts connections when I run the application locally? I want to get a better understanding, definitely for future practices.

### **What I already tried**

- Added both services to a self created network (cbr-open-data). But still no solution.
- Saw that `link` was a possibility but docker was not recommending it since it could be removed from future updates.

All help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postgres container is not running on `localhost`. `localhost` for the app container is the app container itself.

You need to use the IP of the postgres container on the docker network (which both your containers belong to).

You can use the docker-compose in-built DNS to get the IP.
Simply replace:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    database = '...',
    user = '...',
    password = '...',
    port='5432'
)
```

With:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host = 'database',
    database = '...',
    user = '...',
    password = '...',
    port='5432'
)
```

The service name `database` in your compose file, is mapped to the container IP by compose.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I modify this, I get a new error which I also don't understand. ```psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  the database system is starting up```. I've used ```depends_on``` why is it not building the database first then?

Comment: Docker doesn't know when the postgres will finish starting up - it only known when the container itself is up (postgres finishes starting up some time after that). You should add some wait & retry in your application code.

Comment: Thanks man! I've added a wait and retry to my connection.py. Now it works!